# how to copy file to new folder?

Tags: android, image, file, stream, copy

I have a class which show me an image + 2 textview. after pushing button SAVE it should create new folder with name of image despription and to copy image to that folder. Create folder is ok, but file didn't apear in it. Can somebody help me?

```
public class TagActivity extends Activity {

private ImageMetadata imgData;
private TextView imageTitle;
private TextView imageDescription;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tag);

    final Intent i = getIntent();
    final String imgPath = i.getExtras().getString("imgPath");
    final File imgFile = new File(imgPath);
    final String imgName = imgFile.getName();
    imgData = new ImageMetadata(this, imgName);

    imageTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageTitle);
    imageDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.imageDescription);
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(
            ScaledBitmapFactory.decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(imgPath, imageView.getWidth(), 300));

    imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.fromFile(new File(imgPath))));
            return false;
        }
    });
    imageTitle.setText(imgData.getTitle());
    imageDescription.setText(imgData.getDescription());
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tag, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_save:
        final Intent i = getIntent();
        final String imgPath = i.getExtras().getString("imgPath");
        final File imgFile = new File(imgPath);
        final String imgName = imgFile.getName();
        imgData = new ImageMetadata(this, imgName);

        imgData.setTitle(imageTitle.getText().toString().trim());
        imgData.setDescription(imageDescription.getText().toString().trim());
        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + imageDescription.getText().toString());
        boolean success = true;
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            success = folder.mkdirs();
        }

        if (success) {

        } else {
            // Do something else on failure 
        }

        try {
            File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + imgData.getDescription());
            File file = new File(path, imgFile.getName() + ".jpg");
               // the Pictures directory exists? 
                path.mkdirs();
                InputStream is = new FileInputStream(imgPath);
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
                byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
                is.read(data);
                os.write(data);
                is.close();
                os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: After clicking the SAVE button you are first going to see/pick a picture and in onActivityResult you are trying to copy a file. The file copying code is no good. But I think that a file is created only it will be very small. You have write permission in your manifest?

Comment: can you change my code??

Comment: What is the value of `path.getAbsolutePath() ?

Comment: what you mean..?  imgPath is a path where my image exist. but i need to copy image to imageDescription.getText().toString()

Comment: Log.d("value", path.getAbsolutePath()); what does it print?

Comment: i don;t know. i have not logs

Comment: Then do it with a Toast. And who has no Logs???? Just put in that statement.

Comment: sorry for my english, may be i said something wrong -.-'

Comment: Try to find out the path please.

Comment: i didn't understood how to add that log. -.-

Comment: can you see my project??

Comment: Just put that log line in your code.

Comment: im not very good at programming

Comment: `Toast.makeText(context, "path.getAbsolutePath():\n" + path.getAbsolutePath*(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`.

Comment: For that log line: run your app and look in the LogCat.

Comment: it show errors, error path

Comment: Please post a relevant number of lines of that logcat. Do it as post not as comment.

Comment: i made so Toast.makeText(this, "path.getAbsolutePath():\n" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + imgData.getDescription(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: and it sayed absolutepath = sdcars

Comment: sdcard***************

Comment: Use the Toast as I wrote it. Because I want to know path.getAbsolutePath().

Comment: compiler shows error at path

Comment: What kind of error exactly?

Comment: path cannot be resolved

Comment: Then you did place it at the wrong line. It's all about the path in `File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + imgData.getDescription());` so put it after that line.

Comment: hmmmmm it shows mnt/sdcard/mnt/sdcard/aaaaaa

Comment: aaaa that name of description which i made

Comment: /mnt/sdcard/mnt/sdcard/aaaaaa  Aren't forgetting the first slash? Change the path line to `File path = new File (Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(null) + File.separator + imgData.getDescription());`

Comment: yes, i made it. THANKS a lot. i deleted one Environment.getExternalStorageDire‌​ctory()

Comment: hey, if you are not busy, can you help me with another 2 questions??

Comment: may be you know how to resolve them

Comment: If they are different questions then just make another post.

Comment: i made but noone didn't helped me

Comment: this is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154904/listing-thumbnails-per-bucket

Comment: it;s about mediastore

Comment: Please make a new post.

Comment: same as??? you think someone will help? -.-

Comment: Oh people love questions about Mediastore ;-).

Comment: can't post only after 90 minutes :(

Comment: then why noone didn't answered, may be you know answer?? i know that i need to add selection by bucket_list_name in my second class, but i can't implement it :(  Can you look plz??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154904/listing-thumbnails-per-bucket

Comment: sorry, but did you saw my post? XD

Comment: Such a huge discussion in comments!

Answer (score 0):

This looks no good:

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.getExternalStorageDire‌​ctory() 
     + File.separator + imgData.getDescription());
```

If you add a toast to see what path you generate you might solve the issue:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "path.getAbsolutePath():\n" + path.getAbsolutePath*(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```