# Get photos from a specific directory on SD Card

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-file, mediastore

I am trying to use some `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails` code to load all images from a particular directory on my SD card, but getting a null pointer on my `cursor`, which probably means it didn't retrieve anything. Does anyone know how to use `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getContentUri(String volumeName)` correctly? I am assuming it is the specific name of the directory on your SD card, but I guess that's wrong, because my code won't work. The [Android doc pages](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html) are very vague, so of no help, and I can't find a single example where someone is trying to get images from a specific directory. What is usually used is this `MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`, which works, but it pulls photos from who knows where. I think just all your photos on your SD card, anywhere.

Or if you know of a workaround to pull files from a **specific directory on the SD card**, I'd be very thankful.

**UPDATE**

Here is the method where changes need to happen. Currently getting nothing uploaded from SD card, even though 2 photos are in it.

```
private ArrayList<PhotoGridItem> loadSDCard() {

        try {
            // gets directory CutePhotos from sd card
            File cutePhotosDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                    (Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "CutePhotos");
            // lists all files in CutePhotos, loads in Files[] array
            files = cutePhotosDir.listFiles();


            for (File singleFile : files) {
                String filePath = singleFile.getAbsolutePath();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                photoList.add(new PhotoGridItem(bitmap));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return photoList;
    }
```

**PhotoTab.java**

```
package org.azurespot.cutecollection;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import org.azurespot.R;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 2/8/15.
 */
public class PhotoTab extends Fragment{

    private GridView gridView;
    private GridViewPhotoAdapter gvPhotoAdapter;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    //  Cursor used to access the results from querying for images on the SD card.
    protected Cursor cursor;

    // Column index for the Thumbnails Image IDs.
    protected int columnIndex;

    public PhotoTab(){
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_tab, container, false);

        // Set up an array of the Thumbnail Image ID column we want
        String[] thumbNails = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};

        cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query
                (MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getContentUri("/Documents/CutePhotos"),
                thumbNails, // Which columns to return
                null,       // Return all rows
                null,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);

        // Get the column index of the Thumbnails Image ID
        columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);

        // with fragments, make sure you include the rootView when finding id
        gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.photo_grid);
        // Create the Custom Adapter Object, must use v.getContext() instead of
        // getActivity()
        gvPhotoAdapter = new GridViewPhotoAdapter(v.getContext());
        // Set the Adapter to GridView
        gridView.setAdapter(gvPhotoAdapter);


        return v;
    }
    private class GridViewPhotoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        public Context context;
        public ImageView photoView;


        public GridViewPhotoAdapter(Context context) {
            this.context = context;

        }

        public int getCount() {
            return 24;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                photoView = new ImageView(context);

                // Move cursor to current position
                cursor.moveToPosition(position);

                // Get the current value for the requested column
                int imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);

                // Set the content of the image based on the provided URI
                photoView.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageID));
                // positioning the image in the GridView slot
                photoView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                photoView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(320, 320));
            }
            else {
                photoView = (ImageView)convertView;
            }

            return photoView;

        }
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: org.azurespot, PID: 10577
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.azurespot.cutecollection.PhotoTab.onCreateView(PhotoTab.java:65)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5428)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5428)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5428)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5428)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1410)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5428)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17619)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2317)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1412)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1613)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1270)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6691)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:813)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:613)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:583)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:799)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5731)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-18 22:38:22.062  10577-10577/org.azurespot I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 10577 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Do you just want photos from camera captures?

Comment: Yes... from the Pictures directory on my SD card. Then display them all into a `GridView` when the activity loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want only to get photos from camera captures. Here's a good webpage @ [Camera Saving Media](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#saving-media). Look at `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`. It is the directory for pictures. The static class **Environment** is good for other valid directories. Sample relevant code:

```
File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
              Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyApp");
```

Object mediaStorageDir holds the directory name, at least.

Comment: I just noticed you placed all the photos at /Documents/CutePhotos. Is this what you wanted? or is it just for testing purposes for now?

Comment: Hi there, sorry for the delayed response, I was working hard on a separate problem. But I took your advice and changed my `File` directory code. However, it is still not retrieving anything. Do you think there is something wrong elsewhere, like then I change it to `Bitmap`? I updated my question to include the `loadSDCard()` method, where my file I/O happens. See anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post: [Listing thumbnails per bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24154904/listing-thumbnails-per-bucket)
It starts to bring a gridview with all folders. Then upon clicking a folderitem it shows pictures from that folder. Well thats what the OP wanted.

In the onClick listener use `String bucketId =  thumbnails.getId(position);` to get the rigth folder. You need to change class Th a bit to take bucketId as a parameter. Then `selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID + "=" + buckedId;`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to set the Uri correctly. I looked at code from MediaScannerService, and here's what I know. The Uri prefixes can be:

```
content://media/internal/
file://
```

In your case, you could try file://**Documents/CutePhotos**.

Since you know already which folder to use, you can simply use the **File** class, and set the path to /Documents/CutePhotos. But use **Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS** for the correct path prefix.
This way could be more performance efficient since it does not use the database.

Comment: Thanks T.O.A, although I'm not quite sure what you mean. I did update my code with what I think you meant, I hope it's right. I just changed one method, so it's only a few lines. Where in my code is a `Uri`, or is that just in the `Environment...` code? Just not sure what right code would look like.

Comment: So is cutePhotosDir and object files getting the correct files and directory? What problem do you have now?

Comment: Oh my gosh, actually I had the wrong directory. I was supposed to be using PICTURES, not DOCUMENTS. Thank you so much!!!! I found nearly nothing on this topic, so I can't thank you enough!!!

Comment: Well, I am glad for you. Technically I think you could use DOCUMENTS instead of PIC, and then I thought it was weird but I never mentioned it to you.

Comment: Except that DOCUMENTS seems like it's more for text files... I could have used that too, but then my original activity that puts the photos into the SD card would have needed to put it there. So either one could have worked. :) Thanks again.